# Rails - AJAX/JQuery not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

For my application, I have projects where users can make comment (class Newcomments) postings. Right now it posts great but on page refresh. I am trying to use AJAX/JQUERY so that it will post with no page refresh. I am following this [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised?view=asciicast) tutorial.

So right now, the posts are made to my database and the page does not refresh. But when I refresh, the posts shows up. The page that I render my comments for a specific project is on the projects/_comments.html.erb.

**Question: How would I adjust it so that it the new comment made renders?**

**newcomments_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @newcomment = @commentable.newcomments.new(params[:newcomment])

  if @newcomment.save   
         respond_to do |format|
           format.html { redirect_to comments_project_path(@commentable) }
           format.js
         end
  else
     render :new
  end
end
```

**view/newcomments/_form.html.erb**

```
<span class="comment">
<%= form_for [@commentable, @newcomment], remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :content, rows: 3, :class => "span8" %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
    <%= f.submit "Add Comment", :class => "btn btn-header" %>       
<% end %>
</span>
```

**view/newcomments/create.js.erb**

```
$('#newcomment').append('<%= j render(@newcomments) %>');
```

**projects_controller.rb**

```
def comments
  @commentable = @project
  @newcomments = @commentable.newcomments.newest.page(params[:comments_page]).per_page(10)
  @newcomment = Newcomment.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @project.comments }
  end
end
```

**projects/comments.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'comments' %>
```

**projects/_comments.html.erb**

```
<%= render @newcomments %>
```

**view/newcomments/_newcomment.html.erb**

```
<div class="comments"> 
    <%= link_to newcomment.user.name %></strong>
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(newcomment.created_at) %> ago
    <%= newcomment.content %>
</div>

<span class="comment">
    <%= form_for [@commentable, @newcomment] do |f| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.text_area :content, rows: 3, :class => "span8" %>
      </div>

      <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>

      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Add Comment", :class => "btn btn-header" %>
      </div>

    <% end %>

    <% unless newcomment.newcomments.empty? %>
       <%= render @newcomments %>
    <% end %>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try binding AJAX actions as described here:
http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/

Also, consider returning a render comments partial html instead of json comment object, to do so you need to tell in form after :remote directive that :'data-type'=>'html', so that returned html will hit function binded on AJAX success, and then swap html of container div with, for example, jQuery